# UWP:- Listview flickers everytime the collection (binded to the itemsource) is cleared and added

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

Following is the listview (code below), I'm using. Whenever, I clear the observable collection bind to the item source and add new items to the collection, I observe a slight flickering. I tried emptying the transition collection but that disables the animation behavior alone, the flicker still persists.

Any thoughts?

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None" x:Name="View" 
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Details,Mode=OneWay}"
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TestModuleTemplateSelector}"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection/>
                </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
             </ListView>
```

In my userControl xaml.cs, I've the following

```
private ObservableCollection<TestEntityBase> _Details = new ObservableCollection<TestEntityBase>();
    public ObservableCollection<TestEntityBase> Details
    {
        get { return _Details; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _Details, value);
        }
    }
```

The following custom event (subscribed by the userControl.xaml.cs) takes care of adding items to the observable collection above. This event is being triggered from a button click of another user control. Every time, the button is clicked, the items are cleared and added.

```
 private void OnLoadingModuleEntity(IList<EntityBase> entities)
  {     
        Details.Clear();
        foreach (EntityBase entity in entities)
        {
            TestEntityBase entityBase = new TestEntityBase();
            // Conversion logic goes here
            //
            Details.Add(entityBase);                               
        }
  }
```

Data Template Used

```
<Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Name="Sync" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                                           Text="&#xE895;" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10"
                                           ToolTipService.Placement="Top"
                                           Margin="0,0,10,0" Visibility="{x:Bind IsSyncVisible,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox"
                                          IsThreeState="False" Opacity="0.2"
                                          MinWidth="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Height="40" BorderBrush="#f0f0f0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <RelativePanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{x:Bind Name}" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.5" 
                                                   TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <Image Name="Dot1" Source="/test/Assets/abc.jpg" 
                                               Height="6" Width="6" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,8,0,0" 
                                               RelativePanel.RightOf="Name" />
                                        <TextBlock Name="Date1" Text="{x:Bind date2String}" Opacity="0.5" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="Dot1" />
                                        <Image Name="Dot2" Source="/test/Assets/321.jpg" 
                                               Height="6" Width="6" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,8,0,0"
                                               RelativePanel.RightOf="Date1"/>
                                        <Image Name="Name2" Source="/test/Assets/123.jpg" 
                                               Height="10" Width="10" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,5,0,0"
                                               RelativePanel.RightOf="Dot2"/>
                                        <TextBlock Name="Others Text="{x:Bind Others}" Opacity="0.5" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
                                                   RelativePanel.RightOf="Name2"/>
                                    </RelativePanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: you should add the relevant code for how you are binding the item source

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais I've added the relevant code above, Hope this helps.

Comment: are you using a Phisycal Device or an Emulator? remember that you are clearing and then adding items, so it's normal to "blink", and this behaviour is more noticeable in slower devices, one thing you can try is to make a new observable collection, and then match that list to the older collection

Comment: i can make an anwser with a solution, but it's not a "good" solution

Comment: @Karthik I cannot reproduce your issue because I have no idea about how many data are added here when you clear and add new data. I also do not know what controls are using in your listviewitem. So if I simply add textblock with some data. I cannot see the flicker behavior. Can you show more details?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I've updated data template that I've used above. The number of records added is very less (around 50-60) for each clear and add

Comment: @Karthik Hmmm. Still cannot see flickering. I'm sure I have the same code and I think the only difference should be just the images. Since all others are only text. Would you mind to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also please provide your OS version and SDK version

Comment: @Karthik : HAve you got any soultion? I am facing similar issue with  listview having 1 image and 2 labels in Xamarin.Forms UWP for Desktop